# Start background service with schedule and on events

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a background worker that listens to a service bus (Azure Service bus) for messages.
Each message stands for an async task that the service should work on, but for the case that no event is reaching the bus, I also want to trigger the service automatically each day.

The service bus is currently triggered by user events that are generated in different APIs.
This works fine, but who should trigger my service with a certain schedule?
I could of course write a second service that sends a message to the bus each week, but it feels kind of overkill to have a service running only for this task.
I am wondering if there is a better solution how I could do this? Even an Azure Function seems overkill for me...

How would you address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Azure Functions** are **ideal** because you **can create both** a timer triggered, and service bus triggered function in the **same Function App**.

If you feel it is excessive, I suggest the other option is to use the **Azure Web jobs** which can run in the App Services.

You can have timer-triggered Web jobs and use that Web job SDK to trigger them whenever there is a message in the Azure Service Bus.

Refer to the [Scheduled Webjobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON) and [Service Bus triggered webjobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#service-bus-trigger-configuration-version-3x) for more information.